# SubQuery In presto

Tags: presto, trino

```
SELECT
  id,(select something
   from table2 
   where table2.id = table.id) AS "Description"
 FROM table
```

I am getting this error:

```
presto error: Scalar sub-query has returned multiple rows
```

How to write subquery in presto ?

Answer (score 1):

Presto does support nested queries. I think the issue is your semantics.

You are trying to project something from the nested query and it is expecting an scalar value.

It could be something like this -

```
select
id, desc from 
(select table.id as id, something as desc
    from table2 
    where table2.id = table.id)
```

Comment: where is `table` being included in your query?